# Whisper Message in twilio php

Tags: php, twilio

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="other-script">
            4151234567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I try the code above, but it doesn't work for whisper message. I want to ask what to write on the that page of 'other-script'?

Answer (score 1):

Please define problem in detail. 
Refer this page https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/ivrs-extensions
download ivr.zip.

refer this code in - ivr logging and reporting file

```
 header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

echo '<Response>';

$user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];

if ($user_pushed == 0)
{
    echo '<Say>Taking you back to the main menu</Say>';
    echo '<Redirect>handle-incoming-call.xml</Redirect>';
}
else if ($user_pushed == 1)
{
    echo '<Say>Connecting you to agent 1. All calls are recorded.</Say>';
    echo '<Dial record="true">';
    echo '<Number url="screen-caller.xml">+1NNNNNNNNNN</Number>';
    echo '</Dial>';
}
else if ($user_pushed == 2)
{
    echo '<Say>Connecting you to agent 2. All calls are recorded.</Say>';
    echo '<Dial record="true">';
    echo '<Number url="screen-caller.xml">+1NNNNNNNNNN</Number>';
    echo '</Dial>';
}
else {
    echo "<Say>Sorry, that extension is unknown.</Say>";
    echo '<Redirect method="GET">handle-user-input.php?Digits=2</Redirect>';
}

echo '</Response>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`"other-script"` in this case will need to point to a URL that returns the TwiML that you want played to the person receiving the call as the "Whisper" before they are connected to the person calling.

So, if you just wanted the person being called to receive a spoken message before being connected to the caller you would need `"/other-script"` to point to a file that read:

```
<Response>
  <Say>You are being connected to a caller.</Say>
</Response>
```

This would simply read out the message then connect the two calls.

If you want to use the "Whisper" to give the caller an option to decline the call, you would need `"/other-script"` to point to a script that says something like:

```
<Response>
  <Gather action="/handle-input" numDigits="1">
    <Say>You are receiving a call. Dial one to accept and any other digit to decline</Say>
  </Gather>
  <!-- If customer doesn't input anything, prompt and try again. -->
  <Say>Sorry, I didn't get your response.</Say>
  <Redirect>/other-script</Redirect>
</Response>
```

In this case, you will need to provide some TwiML at `"/handle-input"` too. That would need to act based on the number input, so would need to be a script. I see you tagged the question PHP, so here is what it might look like in PHP:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/xml');
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  echo '<Response>';

  $user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];

  if ($user_pushed == 1)
  {
    echo '<Say>Connecting you to the caller.</Say>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<Hangup />';
  }

  echo '</Response>';
?>
```

This would connect the calls if the person receiving the call dialled 1 at the prompt or hang up the call if the person dialled any other digit.

There is a more in depth tutorial on [call whispers and recording calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/ivrs-call-screening-and-recording) available in the Twilio documentation that you might find useful to follow too.